# react state maps not showing data even after updating the states - react js

Tags: reactjs

This one is the main code:

```
const [selectedProductList, setSelectedProductList] = useState([]);

const handleProductSelection = (event) => {
    const { name, value, label } = event;
    setSelectedProductList((selectedProductList) => [
        ...selectedProductList,
        {
            product_id: value,
            quantity: "",
            unit_id: "",
            price_per_unit: "",
        },
    ]);
};
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("selectedProductList >>", selectedProductList);
}, [selectedProductList]);



return (
    <>
        //This select is just using the react select and its triggering handleProductSelection onChange
        <Select
            id="product_id"
            name="product_id"
            onChange={handleProductSelection}
            value={products.filter(function (option) {
                return option.value === formData.product_id;
            })}
            options={products}
            className={` ${
                errors["product_id"] ? "is-invalid" : ""
            }`}
        />

        //THIS IS THE MAIN POINT OF ISSUE
        //THIS ONE IS NOT DISPLAYING
        {selectedProductList.map((prod) => {
            prod && (
                <div>
                    DUMMY <span>{prod.product_id}</span>
                </div>
            );
        })}

    </>
)
```

However, this one does work:

```
//THIS ONE IS CONSOLING ON EVERY CHANGE
{selectedProductList.map((prod) => {
    prod && <div>{console.log(`hit here`)}</div>;
})}
```

What is wrong here. I have added the necessary comment on the code itself.

I have also checked on `useEffect` and it is updating the state correctly which I can verify by looking at the console inside `useEffect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either add a `return`:

```
{selectedProductList.map((prod) => {
  return prod && (
    <div>
      DUMMY <span>{prod.product_id}</span>
    </div>
  );
})}
```

Or you can just syntax without braces `{}`:

```
{selectedProductList.map((prod) => 
  prod && (
    <div>
      DUMMY <span>{prod.product_id}</span>
    </div>
  );
)}
```

Keep in mind that `prod &&` won't avoid rendering elements where `prod` is falsy. It would render something you probably aren't looking for like `false`. You should maybe consider using `Array.prototype.filter` to remove falsy items before mapping them:

```
{selectedProductList.filter(Boolean).map((prod) => 
  <div>
    DUMMY <span>{prod.product_id}</span>
  </div>
)}
```

Hopefully that helps!